# PDO Prepared Statement - Different behavior inside 2 similar methods

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I would like someone to explain me why the first method works only after quoting the placeholder `':cat_id'` in the `WHERE` clause, and requires the `$this->db->query($query);`, otherwise it throws fatal error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens in..."

while the second method doesn't need neither quoting and the `$this->db->query()` method?

```
public function getAllPosts($cat_id = null)
{   
    // Query build
    $query = "SELECT posts.*, users.username, categories.title FROM posts "
            . "INNER JOIN users "
            . "ON posts.user_id = users.id "
            . "INNER JOIN categories "
            . "ON posts.category_id = categories.id ";
    // Filter
    if (!is_null($cat_id))
    {
        $query .= "WHERE category_id = ':cat_id' ";

        // Order query
        $query .= "ORDER BY create_date DESC";
        $this->db->bind(':cat_id', $cat_id);
    }
    else
    {
        $query .= "ORDER BY create_date DESC";

    }
    $this->db->query($query);
    // Run the query


    // Assign Result Set
    $results = $this->db->resultset();
    return $results;
}


public function getCategoryPosts($cat_id)
{   
    $query = "SELECT posts.*, users.username, categories.title FROM posts "
            . "INNER JOIN users "
            . "ON posts.user_id = users.id "
            . "INNER JOIN categories "
            . "ON posts.category_id = categories.id "
            . "WHERE posts.category_id = :cat_id "
            . "ORDER BY create_date DESC";

    $this->db->bind(':cat_id', $cat_id);

    $results = $this->db->resultset();
    return $results;
}
```

### Update:

Here are a echo output of the query from the first method:

#### 1. with quoted:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.username, categories.title FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE category_id = ':cat_id' ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

#### 2. unquoted:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.username, categories.title FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE category_id = :cat_id ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

Comment: Are you missing a space before ORDER BY in the first query?  So :cat_id would actually be :cat_idORDER, I think.

Comment: `category_id = ':cat_id'` should be `category_id = :cat_id`

Comment: @devlincarnate No, that is not the cause for the first method to fail if :cat_id is left unquoted. And actually in my original code, I am not missing the space - let me fix it on here as well.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - that's exactly what it doesn't work. If I left it unquoted - I am getting the fatal error.

Comment: Your edit doesn't match the query you posted. `FROM posts` != `FROM topics` same for the rest of it. Plus where is `$cat_id` assigned? and what does `bind()` do? and this is still wrong `WHERE category_id = ':cat_id'`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, ok I put the right query. The $cat_id is assigned when the function is being called and its an integer. The bind method (inside my db class) is checking for the data type of the parameter and assigns the appropriate PDO CONSTANT to bind the value, in this case: PDO::PARAM_INT.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a trailing space on the following string

```
$query .= "WHERE category_id = ':cat_id'";
```

So you are concatenating it into:

```
WHERE category_id = ':cat_id'ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

If you remove the `'`, you would get:

```
WHERE category_id = :cat_idORDER BY create_date DESC
```

So PDO expects a bound value for `:cat_idORDER`

Also in `getCategoryPosts()` you create a query but never actually use it.

Comment: That isn't the only thing wrong here. What you posted as an answer, will still fail. Being `WHERE category_id = ':cat_id'` Edit: scratch that. I see what you meant here. Not my dv btw.

Comment: how does this differ from my comment?

Comment: He asked for an explanation of what was happening. That is how it is different.

Comment: That's not the cause. Sorry - that was my mistake putting the code in here, sorry for misleading. I updated the code so the space now exists. Still if I left it unquoted, it will lead to the fatal error. I will also paste an echo of the 2 queries.

Comment: @tafvita `pdo::query()` does not prepare a query for use with placeholders. Your error is probably because you are binding values to a query with no placeholders. Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston I'm afraid you're in for a long haul on this one.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston - i guess i differ in my belief that syntax errors don't need complete explanations, and should not be posted as answers.